# Dovecot/Postfix with SSL on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, postfix, dovecot

I've been running through a tutorial at: http://www.cerebellumstrategies.com/amazon-linux-postfix-dovecot/ and everything works through the entire tutorial right up to checking the authentication.

While inside the instance, I can run:

```
[ec2-user@domU-... ~]$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect localhost:25
CONNECTED(00000003)
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
140326462789448:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:699:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 238 bytes and written 148 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-05-61-27 ~]$
```

But from my own laptop:

```
Drew-Sonnes-MacBook-Pro:~ drew$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.symbiosislaboratories.com:25
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
```

I have port 25 open in my security group (and have for a few weeks). For the purpose of debugging my problem, I have iptables turned off:

```
[ec2-user@domU-... ~]$ sudo service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

I have requested my reverse DNS and port 25 open from Amazon, and they put that through a couple of days ago. I've made sure my DNS is resolving correctly. I've run through the tutorial, fixed typos, double & triple checked my settings, and can't find anything I've done wrong. Does anyone else know of anything else which would be stopping this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is with SASL. Key is the key, pem is the CA file, and crt and issued cert.

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/main.cf:

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
mailbox_size_limit = 0
allow_percent_hack = no
## Specify the keys/certificates
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
##
```

/etc/dovecot/master.cf:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet    n       -       n       -       -      smtpd    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtps     inet    n       -       n       -       -      smtpd    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```